# How do I pass the date range selected in the daterangepicker to a variable or back to my input textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

My javascript below using preset ranges for DateRangePicker -
I need to pass the selected start and end dates to two variables call StartDate and EndDate or pass it back to my LogiXML input text box.  I am not sure how to do this.  Please help.

Note: I don't want to run the daterangepicker logic for two different input fields(from and to). I want to use one input field but the start and end dates are passed to two separate variables.

I am using comiseo.daterangepicker  please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#inpDatePicker").daterangepicker({
                        presetRanges: [{
                            text: 'Today',
                            dateStart: function() { return moment() },
                            dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
                        }, {
                            text: 'Month to Date',
                            dateStart: function() { return moment().startOf('month')  },
                            dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
                        }, {
                            text: 'Quarter to Date',
                            dateStart: function() { return moment().startOf('quarter') },
                            dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
                        }, {
                            text: 'Year to Date',
                            dateStart: function() { return moment().startOf('Year') },
                            dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
                        }],
                        applyOnMenuSelect: true,
                        datepickerOptions: {
                            minDate: 0,
                            maxDate: null,
                            numberOfMonths : 3,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true

                        }
                    })
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Declaration:

```
$("#inpDatePicker").daterangepicker({...})
```

Event Trigger (This goes in after an event is fired):

```
var range = $("#inpDatePicker").daterangepicker("getRange");
$("#range_start").val(range['start']);
$("#range_end").val(range['end']);
```

HTML:

```
<input id="inpDatePicker" name="inpDatePicker" type="text">
<input type="hidden" name="range_start" id="range_start">
<input type="hidden" name="range_end" id="range_end">
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("#inpDatePicker").val()` will return an object with `start` and `end`. You can listen to your `$("#inpDatePicker")`'s `change` event to see when to get the values.

```
$("#inpDatePicker").daterangepicker({
  onChange: function() {
    StartDate = $("#inpDatePicker").val().start;
    EndDate = $("#inpDatePicker").val().end;
  }
}
```

Comment: The StartDate is returning undefined and is not populating my inpDatePicker field.   here is more clarity: I have a button with two input boxes button = btnDatePicker  input = inpStartDate and inpEndDate text boxes.  the datepicker is triggered on btnDatePicker but I want to pass the individual dates to inpStartDate and inpEndDate - in other words is someone selects jan 1 - dec 21, 2014 then inpStartDate should be set to jan 1 and inpEndDate should be set to dec 21.  how do I pass the values?

Comment: ``inpStartDate.val($("#inpDatePicker").val().start);`` and similar for inpEndDate

Comment: szupie - I am using comiseo-datepicker js  and when I use the  inpStartDate.val($("#inpDatePicker").val().start); i get an error and when I use $("#inpStartDate").val($("#btnDatePicker").val().start);
    $("#inpEndDate").val($("#btnDatePicker").val().end);  it doesn't work it is still not passing the date to my input fields please help.

Comment: What error are you getting? If you output ``$("#inpDatePicker").val()`` to the console and you're seeing the dates, then your remaining problem is getting that data into your input field.

Comment: the problem is $("#inpDatePicker").val().start; is undefined  start is undefined -there is no values in start.   I see the range when I use $("#inpDatePicker").val()  but how do I parse it into two separate Input textboxes...this is the problem the dates are not appearing in my input textboxes

Comment: Oh I see, I had misread the documentations. ``$("#inpDatePicker").val()`` will return the date range as a JSON string, so you have to parse it like so ``JSON.parse($("#inpDatePicker").val()).start``.

Comment: Thanks Szupie that worked now how do I format the date JSON.parse($("#inpDatePicker").val()).start??  I want to format as MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Datepicker has [an option to display the date in a custom format](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/#options). In this case, you would change the ``altFormat``.