# DateRangePicker bootstrap plugin display one format send another

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, format, daterangepicker

I have a dashboard that is requesting data from a servlet, the servlet is pulling data from a DB and needs the time formatted for a `timestamp`  :`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+00:00`. I have a parser on the servlet set up to parse this string to an sql timestamp.

I'm using the [daterangpicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) Bootstrap plugin. I would like to display the date format on the dashboard like so: `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm - DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm`

I'm currently formatting the date like so: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss - YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`

Then in my JavaScript I'm slicing it to the format I need to send:

```
var startDate = $('#range').val().slice(0, 19) + '+00:00';
var endDate = $('#range').val().slice(22, 41) + '+00:00';
```

I could obviously do a lot more slicing to achieve this, but maybe there's an easier solution?

I've tried two solutions I found on stack but both methods failed to pull the dateRange as a dateRange object: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548737/how-do-i-pass-the-date-range-selected-in-the-daterangepicker-to-a-variable-or-ba) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548737/how-do-i-pass-the-date-range-selected-in-the-daterangepicker-to-a-variable-or-ba)